# how to make a iten of my array walk through all the other itens on javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

So the question its I need to make a function who gonna do this:

```
xRunning(["x", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"]);
⁠// Must return:
⁠// ["x", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"]
⁠// ["-", "x", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"]
⁠// ["-", "-", "x", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"]
⁠// .....
⁠// ["-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "x", "-"]
⁠// ["-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "x"]
```

how you guys would make it?

thats the only idea I had, but it will replace all itens for 'x'

```
function xRunning(array){

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if ( array[i] !== "x"){
      array[i] = "x"
    }else{
    }   
}
return array
}
```

thats the only idea I had, but it will replace all itens for 'x'

Comment: OK so `array[i]` is the element at the current index. You'll need to write some code that changes `array[i - 1]` to a dash if `i` is greater than zero (because you can't change the index at `-1`).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve your output would be to provide the length of the array as an argument to your `xRunning()` function. You can then use a loop to `fill()` each child array, setting the `x` in the appropriate position. Something like this:

```js
function xRunning(len) {
  const output = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    const arr = (new Array(len)).fill('-');
    arr[i] = 'x';
    output.push(arr);
  }
  return output
}

console.log(xRunning(3)); // 3 used here to make output easier to read
```